# jQuery: changed input value is not used for new addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, addition

I have a hidden input field, wich has the value 0:

```
<input type="hidden" class="test" value="0" />
```

Now I added a button with some JS to add 0.5 to the value each time the button is clicked:

```
<a class="addition-input">Click me</a>
```

Here is the JS part:

```
$('a.addition-input').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var currentValue = parseInt($('input.test').val());
     var step         = 0.5;
     var newValue     = currentValue + step;

     $('input.test').val(newValue);
});
```

So, the first time i click the link/button, the value gets from "0" to "0.5".
But then, when I click the link/button the second time, it won't change, it just stays "0.5".

I think that jQuery doesn't get the new input value by the second time click, it probably thinks the value is "0".

How can I fix that?

**Update:**

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7pvjrve/1/

Comment: .5 is not an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
var currentValue = parseFloat($('input.test').val());
```

instead of

```
var currentValue = parseInt($('input.test').val());
```

parseInt() converts `0.5` to `0` everytime and the value you get is `0.5` which is actually the `step` value

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/657/